# NPM run watch resulting in error Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-echo

I am receiving this error when I try to run `npm run watch`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\wamp64\www\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js'
```

I am currently using

```
Laravel Framework 5.7.16
NPM 6.4.1
```

Thank you in advance

Edit: yes, I have run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first install your node modules with:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the package Laravel-mix, install it running:

```
npm install laravel-mix --save-dev
```

Also check if you have your webpack.config.js inside the main folder of your app, if not check for the docs on how to get it: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/3.0/installation